# How can I solve: $\frac {3x-2}2 - \frac {4x-5}3=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a a student and I am having difficulty with answering this question. I keep getting $6$ as my value for x  whereas it is wrong. Please may I have a step by step solution to this question so that I won't have difficulties with answering these type of questions in the future.

Question: Solve $$\frac {3x-2}2 - \frac {4x-5}3=2$$

This is what I did to get the answer:
$$2(3x-2) - 3(4x-5) = 12$$
 $$6x-4 - 12x+15 = 12$$
$$6x - 12x = 12+4-15$$
$$-6x = 1$$
$$x = -6 $$

Kind Regards help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean $\frac {3x-2}2 - \frac {4x-5}3=2$?

Comment: Please do learn the easy directions to properly write mathematics in this site. Your equation is very hard to understand and most probably, impossible to know what **exactly** you meant (at least use parentheses!)

Comment: @lulu that is what I meant

Comment: I will edit accordingly.  [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting

Comment: Hint:  to solve, clear the denominators.  Thus we get $3\times (3x-2)-2\times (4x-5)=6\times 2\implies 9x-6 -(8x-10)=12\implies 9x-6 -8x +10=12$  Can you finish from here?

Comment: I don't quite understand

Comment: My last comment really should be enough.  If I had to guess, I'll bet you didn't distribute the sign across $(4x-5)$ correctly.

Comment: I multiplied both sides by $6=3\times 2$, the least common denominator for your fractions.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me the step by step solution as an answer

Comment: Well, let's try it this way:  edit your post to indicate how you got to $x=6$.  I'll edit it for formatting, but please use parentheses.

Comment: Looking at your attempt, there are a number of mistakes. First, the common denominator is $6$...so you need to multiply the first term by $\frac 33$ and the second by $\frac 22$.  Also, it is not true that $-6x=1\implies x = -6$.

Comment: So do I do  3×(3x−2)3×2−2×(4x−5)2×3=2
 3×(3x−2)3×2−2×(4x−5)2×3=2

 9x−66−8x−106=2
 9x−66−8x−106=2

(9x−6)−(8x−10)6=2
(9x−6)−(8x−10)6=2

(9x−6)−(8x−10)=12

Comment: You have a mistake in the second line. It's not $2(3x - 2) - 3(4x-5) = 12$ but $3(3x - 2) - 2(4x-5) = 12$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $$\frac{ 3x-2}{2} - \frac{4x-5}{3} = 2$$ is the same as 
$$\ \frac{3\times( 3x-2)}{3  \times 2} -  \frac{2\times(4x-5)}{2\times3} = 2$$
or equivalently 
$$\ \frac{   9x-6 }{6} -  \frac{ 8x-10 }{6} = 2$$
which is the same as 
 $$  \frac{   (9x-6)-(8x-10) }{6}  = 2$$
so we get
$$(9x-6)-(8x-10) =12 $$
so $$x=8 $$

Answer (score 3):

The mistake you made is that **you didn't cross multiply**. Instead of doing:

\begin{align}
\frac{\color{#f00}3}{\color{#f00}3} \cdot \frac {(3x-2)}{\color{#0000ff}2} - \frac{\color{#0000ff}2}{\color{#0000ff}2} \cdot \frac {(4x-5)}{\color{#f00}3}=2
\end{align}

You did
\begin{align}
\frac {2(3x-2)}{2} - \frac {3(4x-5)}{3} &= 2 \\
\frac {2(3x-2)}{6} - \frac {3(4x-5)}{6} &= 2 \\
{2(3x-2)} - {3(4x-5)}&=12 \\
...
\end{align}

So you noticed that we need to combine the fractions but you didn't combine them properly. If you want to get the same denominator then you need to find a *common multiple* of the denominators of your fractions. The easiest way to do that is to **cross multiply**.

Can you solve it from here?

\begin{align}
\frac {3(3x-2) - 2(4x-5)}{6} =2
\end{align}

Let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: Thank you for telling me where I went wrong

Comment: No problem! I am not sure if you are familiar with the Math.se system however, if you found my answer useful or any other answer then please be sure hit the check mark below the "up", "down" buttons to the left. This helps the user (and yourself) and closes a loop, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Get the same denominator, 6, for both terms.

$\frac33*\frac{3x-2}2 - \frac22 * \frac{4x-5}3 = \frac{9x-6}6 - \frac{8x-10}6 = 2$

Step 2: Combine terms

$\frac{9x-8x-6+10}6 = \frac{x+4}6 = 2$

Step 3: Solve for x

$x+4 = 12$

$x=8$

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways you could solve for $x;$ here is one way:

$\frac{3x-2}{2} - \frac{4x-5}{3} = 2 \rightarrow$

$\frac{3}{2}x - 1 - (\frac{4}{3}x - \frac{5}{3}) = 2 \rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{6}x + \frac{2}{3} = 2 \rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{6}x = \frac{4}{3} \rightarrow$

$x = 8$